# Adjusting the order of asyncTasks

Tags: android, android-asynctask, stack, queue

Is it possible to enforce/recommend an order of created AsyncTasks?

Instead of a queue-like order, I want it to be more like a stack, so that if a new instance of AsyncTask is created and executed, it will have more of a chance of being run than the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *might* be able to pull this off on API Level 11+ via `executeOnExecutor()` where you supply your own `Executor`. Beyond that, you would need to completely roll this yourself, with your own thread pool and using `Handler` or `post()` or `runOnUiThread()` for the work to be done on the main application thread.

Comment: i was thinking that i would need to go to such actions. is it possible to give the CTOR of the Executor a customized blockigQueue , so that it will work like a stack ? on the other hand, i can't know for sure what would be the impact of such a thing . is there a tutorial for Executor?

Comment: @androiddeveloper: I have never created my own `Executor`. It is part of standard Java, and so there probably is material about it on the Internet, or possibly in _Java Concurrency in Practice_ or other Java books with a heavy emphasis on threading.

Comment: i see . thank you . i will try to do something and i hope that i will remember to update this post and put here a sample code .

Comment: executeOnExecutor() is not available on API Levels less then 11, is there any work around for this?

Comment: @Adhavan: Not really, other than perhaps grabbing the newer `AsyncTask` implementation out of the repo, refactoring it onto your own package, and using it.

Comment: @CommonsWare i have a doubt, what changes did google do on Async task in  Android1.5 1.6 and 3.0 versions??.i really didnt find any difference while executing multiple async task in Android 2.3 and 3.0. Both behaves exactly same.

Comment: @Adhavan: Please ask questions in a new question, by clicking the "Ask Question" link in the upper-right corner of your Web page.

Comment: sorry i thought its some way related.Will post with the sample i did.Thanks

Comment: FYI - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10995281/what-change-did-really-happen-in-async-task-after-android-gingerbread