# multiple asyntask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

This is somewhat design specific question but I am looking for right  advice.

In  my app I have 6 pages  A,B,C... each of which will download data  from server and display it. In this case among  below mentioned approaches which one will  be good.

1.For each A,B,C write inner asynctask class
2.write separate  asyntasks like asyntaskA,asyntskB  etc for each  of these activities
3. write a single asynctask and route request of each activity through a requestcontroller class which creates instance of asyctask by passing context,url parameters

If the second approach is taken, is it possible to run one `Activity` and another `Activity` in `onpause` state while its `asynctask` still running?

Comment: Per default all `AsyncTask` are executed on a global single `Thread` in newer Android versions. If you experience slow task completion read the [Order of execution](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) section.

Comment: As zapl mentioned, the threadpool behaviour is differ across different OS version. Check out [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10995281/what-change-did-really-happen-in-async-task-after-android-gingerbread/10996600#10996600) for a quick history catch up about AsyncTask.

Answer (score 1):

In each page, if you are doing the same kind of operation (As in this case, downloading data and displaying it), you need not write separate `AsyncTask` classes. Just create as much instances as you need and call the `execute()` method. `AsyncTask` class will handle this in thread safe way.

Second part of your question is bit unclear, but if you meant switching between activities, it is possible with multiple instances of a single `AsyncTask`. You'll need to save and restore the activity states.

If the operation you performing is time consuming, say more than few seconds, it's not safe using an `AsyncTask`. The better option will be a `Service`.

Answer (score 0):

There's no problem with multiple AsyncTasks. In one of my apps I have a grid-view with images and there's an AsyncTask for every image loading and generating a thumbnail image. They all run in parallel quite nicely.